# SPFx Developement Environment Setup issue

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, spfx-webparts

I am facing critical issue in setting up development environment for **SPFx**.

I have refereed following link Link:
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/set-up-your-development-environment

1) I have installed **latest LTS version of Node(v8.10.0)** package on E: drive (other than system drive and I have no installation access).

2) I have tried installing the Yeoman and gulp on the same path (other than system drive) and it's installed successfully.

3) when I try to create webpart on same path it gives following error:

[image]

Logs:

```
3199 verbose stack SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near '...dencies":{"@types/ass'
3199 verbose stack     at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
3199 verbose stack     at parseJson (E:\Development\node_modules\npm\node_modules\pacote\node_modules\make-fetch-happen\node_modules\node-fetch-npm\node_modules\json-parse-better-errors\index.js:7:17)
3199 verbose stack     at consumeBody.call.then.buffer (E:\Development\node_modules\npm\node_modules\pacote\node_modules\make-fetch-happen\node_modules\node-fetch-npm\src\body.js:96:50)
3199 verbose stack     at <anonymous>
3199 verbose stack     at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:188:7)
3200 verbose cwd E:\Projects\Development\SPFx\helloworld-webpart
3201 verbose Windows_NT 10.0.15063
3202 verbose argv "E:\\Development\\node.exe" "E:\\Development\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "--cache-min" "86400"
3203 verbose node v8.10.0
3204 verbose npm  v5.6.0
3205 error Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near '...dencies":{"@types/ass'
3206 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

Thanks in Advance

Comment: can check what the error says in the log file ?

Comment: @GautamSheth, I have updated code adding log text

Comment: can you try `npm cache clean --force` and then `npm set registry https://registry.npmjs.org/` in your command line and create a new project to try again ?

Comment: @GautamSheth, process stuck : "[ .................] / fetchMetadata: sill fetchPackageMetaData error for autoprefixer@6.3.7 Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near '...~0.8.1"},"devDependen'"

Comment: looks like some issue with NPM, try to start your generator using `yo @microsoft/sharepoint --package-manager yarn` or `yo @microsoft/sharepoint --package-manager pnpm` and check with a new project

Comment: @GautamSheth, 1)I have installed node in E drive 2)gulp and yeoman are added in "AppData/Roaming" 3) I am creating project in E drive in same folder where I installed node. So would this work ?

Comment: have never tried it in E drive, but it should work. No reason not to work !

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/80427/discussion-between-gopal-zadafiya-and-gautam-sheth).

Comment: I'm using node 8.11.1 and have no issues. Be sure to update yeoman and the spfx generator.

Comment: @elsni, how to update yeoman and spfx generator ?

Comment: @GopalZadafiya: 
yo (then select update generators)
to upgrade yo itself, please google, there are probably some issues which are explained in several blog posts

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Turns out this issue seems to be related to Firewall or some other security restriction which was preventing download of files nothing to do with MS.

Once the connection was changed and the machine connected to the open internet, were able to create the hello world webpart correctly.

Would suggest that you download the files required for the project via NPM to be done via an open connection or create some firewall rule which will allow such files to be downloaded.